# data duplication in tableview cell when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

Im getting json data from the backend , and displaying them in the tableview.
each object is displayed in a cell, some objects have same names, other have different.

the problem is when I am scrolling the tableview, the object names are changing. My code in  cellForRow atIndex path:

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell2";
ProccessingOrderTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
Order *order = self.orderArray[indexPath.row];
NSString *role = [NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"userRole"];
if([role isEqualToString:@"brand.operator"]){
    cell.branchName.hidden = NO;
    NSString *roleDisplay = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"Branch name: " ,order.branch.name ] ;
    cell.branchName.text = roleDisplay;
} else if([role isEqualToString:@"corporate.operator"]){
    cell.branchName.hidden = NO;
    NSString *roleDisplay = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@ \n%@%@", @"Branch name: " , order.branch.name,@"Brand name: ",order.branch.brand.name ] ;
    cell.branchName.text = roleDisplay;
} else {
    cell.branchName.hidden = YES;
}
```

the field "cell.branchName.text" is changing on scrolling,

Any idea whats happening?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38135090/3937664

Comment: can you please attach screenshot

Comment: what is the correlation between those names you mention above the code for `cellForRow` and the `cell.branchName.text`?

Comment: cell.branchName.text is the name of the label, where I want to display the text received, which is in "order.branch.name", cellfoRow, is just the tableview method

Comment: I was asking about `firstObject.name = @"MyName";` - how does this go with the rest of the question?

Comment: you can use cell that cell is reusable so that problem arrise

Comment: this is an example, just forget it, I was explaining what I am doing

Comment: Try creating `ProccessingOrderTableViewCell` with an initializer - if the problem disappears, then the problem is really in reusing cells

Comment: Unrelated to the issue but retrieving the (same value of ) `userRole` from user defaults in each call of `cellForRow` is unnecessarily expensive.

Comment: how do I create ProccessingOrderTableViewCell with an initializer?

Comment: @Ali.Jab can you give a gif for your problem? It's easier for use to find solution.

Comment: the problem is just that data is changing in tableViewCell when scrolling the table view

Answer (score 0):

Cell gets reused when you scroll in UITableView and UICollectionView. Hence you see the old text for fraction of second and gets updated to proper value.

Use `prepareForReuse` of UITableViewCell method  to clear the textFields before reuse to avoid such issues

In your `ProccessingOrderTableViewCell` write

```
-(void) prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    //clear your textfields here
    self.branchName.text = @"";
   //clear/reset other UI components as well
}
```

Comment: As you see in his question, he handle every case to update `self.branchName` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` so `prepareForReuse` in this case is useless.

Comment: so whats the solution? @ trungduc